# Checking app release signature at runtime -- chicken and egg?

Tags: android, security, release, signature

I'm trying check my app's release signature at runtime to prevent tampering.  However, what I've been reading is that I need to log the signature during a run so that I can hard code it into my app for runtime comparison.  But I see two problems with this:
1) The signature obtained while debugging (reading the log) will be different than the release signature.
2) If I get the release signature and then put it into my code for runtime comparison, won't that change the signature for the next release build... hence a chicken and egg problem?
What am I missing?  Do static final strings not change the signature?  Likewise, if I log release output does the log code not change the signature? What does and doesn't impact the release signature?

Answer (score 3):

If compute the signature over bytes that include the signature itself then yes, you will have *chicken and egg problem*. But you don't have to: compute the signature over everything but the signature. That's in fact how signatures generated by `jarsigner` [are done](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html#JSWOR696).

But what I think you really want, since `apk` files are already signed, is to check if the signer information matches your own. And that can be done by comparing the package's signer certificate with your own certificate.

You can see an adopted example from [Android Security Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/android-security-cookbook) that performs such check [here](https://github.com/joswr1ght/ValidateSigningCertificate/blob/master/src/app/src/main/java/com/willhackforsushi/validatesigningcertificate/MainActivity.java#L45).

Comment: So, does that mean the code you provided a link to will not change the signature by adding the line:  private static String CERTIFICATE_SHA1 = "DD1C1115D3E2CB99AB05F98F0C8190E16FDDA4C7";  as listed in that link?  In other words, will updating that SHA1 code not change the resulting signature?

Comment: The `CERTIFICATE_SHA1` constant is the thumbprint of the certificate whose private key you use to sign the application archive. It is constant as long as you use the same certificate it doesn't change with every signing.

Answer (score 3):

If I want to change your apk here are the steps:

1. Open your apk with a an unzip program
2. Get one or two resources out of it ( ex: class files).
3. Make changes to it ( de-copmile, change, recompile)
4. Put it back in the APK.
5. Sign it
6. Publish it

I will have some problem At step 5, as I don't have your private key and your signature, I should create my own and sign it with my key. Then I should hope that no one checks the sign before installing the app ( which no one does! ).

So my tampered app has two differences with your app, changed resources AND changed sign certificate.

If you want to check the changed resources, ( signature over bytes) you will have the chicken and egg problem.

The easiest way to stop me is to **hard code your app signature** and check if it is changed at **run time**.

The sample code is at https://gist.github.com/scottyab/b849701972d57cf9562e

A simple method for this check:

```
private boolean validateAppSignature() {
        APP_SIGN= "f10e2821bbbea527ea02200352313bc059445190";
        PackageInfo packageInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            // SHA256 the signature
            String AppSign = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(signature.toByteArray());
            return APP_SIGN.equalsIgnoreCase(AppSign);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Of course this is not a 100% solution even the obfuscated code can be changed. So I may find a way to by pass this check. But you make tampering harder for me :)